# VB.Net 2008 Buttons acts as Tab Controls

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a way to design things differently in my project. Instead of using TabControls I wish to use Buttons (Instead of pressing the tabs on the top I would like to press the Buttons on the left-side). These buttons when pressed they have their own Panel where each has their own respective content.

```
Select Case tabAdmin.SelectedIndex
            Case 0
                If txtCode_Patient.Text = "" Then
                    txtCode_Patient.Focus()
                Else
                    cmdAdminister.Focus()
                End If
            Case 1
                If txtD_Patient.Text = "" Then
                    txtD_Patient.Focus()
                Else
                    cmdRefresh.Focus()
                End If
            Case 2
                If txtI_Patient.Text = "" Then
                    txtI_Patient.Focus()
                Else
                    cmdI_CUser.Focus()
                End If
            Case 3
                If txtStat_CS.Text = "" Then
                    txtStat_CS.Focus()
                Else
                    cmdStat_Refresh.Focus()
                End If

        End Select
```

The code above is similar to what my project acts and it works with TabControls. I want to do a similar thing but this time, like I said before, pressing Buttons on the left-side. How can I do a similar thing ?

**UPDATE:**

I found a way for this one but now my concern is how do I make it look like one of its default button 3D look-alike?

```
Public Class Tab
    Inherits TabControl
    Private Property DoubledBuffered As Boolean

    Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        DoubledBuffered = True
        SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed
        ItemSize = New Size(30, 110)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateHandle()
        MyBase.CreateHandle()

        Alignment = TabAlignment.Left
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        Dim B As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
        Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)

        G.Clear(Color.AliceBlue)

        For i = 0 To TabCount - 1
            Dim TabRectangle As Rectangle = GetTabRect(i)

            If i = SelectedIndex Then
                '//Selected
                G.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkSlateGray, TabRectangle)
            Else
                '//Not Selected
                G.FillRectangle(Brushes.AntiqueWhite, TabRectangle)
            End If

            G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, Font, Brushes.Black, TabRectangle, New StringFormat With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})

        Next

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(B.Clone, 0, 0)
        G.Dispose() : B.Dispose()
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `tabAdmin.Appearance = TabAppearance.Buttons`

Comment: `I am looking for a way to design things differently` Only if the current approach did not work for you. Always research alternatives before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CheckBox` control instead of `Button`, but set `Appearance = Button`, that way it looks exactly like a button can remains in the "pressed" state when clicked.

To shift between content, put each of your sub-forms into their own `UserControl` instances, then host them within a `Panel` control, then switch the `.Visibility` property of each sub-form according to which `CheckBox` was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Outlook-style side bar available on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14238/OutlookBar-A-Simplified-Outlook-Style-Sidebar-Cont). It has a VB version as well as C# and although it's knocking on a bit now, you could always adapt this to look a bit nicer. I have used it in the past and it worked pretty well as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected tab via `tabAdmin.SelectedIndex = 0` (or `1`, `2`, etc, but remember it is 0 based)

You may also set the tab by the tab's name via `tabAdmin.SelectedTab = TabName`

Answer (score 0):

Use a common click event handler for the buttons.  Store the relevant tabindex in the Tag property of the buttons.  Then tabAdmin.SelectedIndex equals the tag of the clicked button cast as integer.